# How do I make the debug build faster for Android in .NET MAUI?

Tags: visual-studio, maui

At some point today, between fiddling with .NET 7 on my project and reverting it back to .NET 6, my debug loading time for Android has increased. When VS is done doing its thing and it throws the app over to the emulator, the emulator hangs for about a minute on the splash screen of my app, the VS status bar says "XAML Hot Reload initializing...", and the Output window shows it loading all sorts of assemblies.

The way it acted before was, it would spend about 5-10 seconds on the splash screen.

I tried Googling for an answer and fast deployment came up, but I can't seem to find that option anywhere.

I had made a backup to my GitHub last night, so I pulled that, but I still get the same symptoms, leading me to believe there's a setting in VS somewhere.

Any ideas out there?

Edit:

It's failing to load a lot of the assemblies, here's an excerpt from the Output window:

```
19:38:43:988    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll
19:38:43:988    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.prometheansoftworks.myapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll [External]
19:38:44:270    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.dll
19:38:44:270    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Plugin.LocalNotification.dll
19:38:44:477    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.prometheansoftworks.myapp/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.dll [External]
19:38:44:632    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.prometheansoftworks.myapp/files/.__override__/Plugin.LocalNotification.dll [External]
19:38:44:985    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll
19:38:45:010    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.prometheansoftworks.myapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll [External]
19:38:45:601    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll
19:38:45:618    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.prometheansoftworks.myapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll [External]
19:38:45:723    [ftworks.budgif] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
19:38:45:725    [ftworks.budgif] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
19:38:45:788    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.UI.dll
19:38:45:789    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Fragment.dll
19:38:45:789    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Common.dll
19:38:45:796    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.dll
19:38:45:859    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.prometheansoftworks.myapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.UI.dll [External]
19:38:45:876    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.prometheansoftworks.myapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Fragment.dll [External]
19:38:46:172    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.prometheansoftworks.myapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Common.dll [External]
19:38:46:653    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.prometheansoftworks.myapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.dll [External]
```

Edit 2:
I did a new project. Before the emulator starts, output window has:

```
16:30:52:881    > am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.companyname.ugg/crc642c019dd32d8d358c.MainActivity"
16:30:52:996    > Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.companyname.ugg/crc642c019dd32d8d358c.MainActivity }
16:30:53:646    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Ugg.dll
```

While the emulator is loading the new app:

```
16:30:55:053    [companyname.ug] Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
16:30:55:053    [companyname.ug] Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
16:30:55:053    [CompatibilityChangeReporter] Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10107; state: ENABLED
16:30:55:053    [GraphicsEnvironment] ANGLE Developer option for 'com.companyname.ugg' set to: 'default'
16:30:55:053    [GraphicsEnvironment] Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
16:30:55:053    [NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
16:30:55:053    [NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
16:30:55:053    [debug-app-helper] Checking if libmonodroid was unpacked to /data/app/~~dc_k1QI1zDfTGXUHfSXVSw==/com.companyname.ugg-LIodHf5CoLdLXZOW2fa8pg==/lib/x86_64/libmonodroid.so
16:30:55:053    [debug-app-helper] Native libs extracted to /data/app/~~dc_k1QI1zDfTGXUHfSXVSw==/com.companyname.ugg-LIodHf5CoLdLXZOW2fa8pg==/lib/x86_64, assuming application/android:extractNativeLibs == true
16:30:55:054    [debug-app-helper] Setting up for DSO lookup in app data directories
16:30:55:054    [debug-app-helper] Added filesystem DSO lookup location: /data/app/~~dc_k1QI1zDfTGXUHfSXVSw==/com.companyname.ugg-LIodHf5CoLdLXZOW2fa8pg==/lib/x86_64
16:30:55:054    [debug-app-helper] Using runtime path: /data/app/~~dc_k1QI1zDfTGXUHfSXVSw==/com.companyname.ugg-LIodHf5CoLdLXZOW2fa8pg==/lib/x86_64
16:30:55:054    [debug-app-helper] checking directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/lib`
16:30:55:054    [debug-app-helper] directory does not exist: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/lib`
16:30:55:054    [debug-app-helper] Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/user/0/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
16:30:55:054    [debug-app-helper] Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/app/~~dc_k1QI1zDfTGXUHfSXVSw==/com.companyname.ugg-LIodHf5CoLdLXZOW2fa8pg==/lib/x86_64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
16:30:55:054    [debug-app-helper] Mono runtime found at: /data/app/~~dc_k1QI1zDfTGXUHfSXVSw==/com.companyname.ugg-LIodHf5CoLdLXZOW2fa8pg==/lib/x86_64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
16:30:55:054    [companyname.ug] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
16:30:55:054    [DOTNET] JNI_OnLoad: JNI_OnLoad in pal_jni.c
16:30:55:054    [monodroid] Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__`
16:30:55:054    [companyname.ug] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
16:30:55:054    [monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=10.0.2.2:53899,embedding=1
16:30:55:054    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Ugg.dll
16:30:55:054    [monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46080
16:30:55:054    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Mono.Android.dll
16:30:55:054    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.dll
16:30:55:054    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Java.Interop.dll
16:30:55:054    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Collections.dll
16:31:01:259    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Mono.Android.dll [External]
16:31:01:280    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.dll [External]
16:31:01:345    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Java.Interop.dll [External]
16:31:01:384    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Collections.dll [External]
16:31:01:399    Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives(System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32)' to /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:124 [0x00000].
16:31:01:408    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Threading.dll
16:31:01:434    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Threading.dll [External]
16:31:01:468    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
16:31:01:486    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll [External]
16:31:01:507    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Threading.Thread.dll
16:31:01:508    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
16:31:01:524    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Threading.Thread.dll [External]
16:31:01:544    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll [External]
16:31:01:570    [companyname.ug] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
16:31:01:825    Loaded assembly: data-0x7bdd9325d020 [External]
16:31:01:841    Loaded assembly: data-0x7bdd9327d040 [External]
16:31:01:896    Loaded assembly: data-0x7bde39db0e70 [External]
16:31:02:048    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly netstandard.dll
16:31:02:084    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/netstandard.dll [External]
16:31:02:119    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Linq.dll
16:31:02:141    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Linq.dll [External]
16:31:02:162    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
16:31:02:162    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
16:31:02:171    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
16:31:02:171    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
16:31:02:172    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
16:31:02:199    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll [External]
16:31:02:236    Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointSendToIde(System.String)' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:423 [0x00000].
16:31:02:243    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Json.dll
16:31:02:351    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Text.Json.dll [External]
16:31:02:354    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
16:31:02:376    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll [External]
16:31:02:390    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ComponentModel.dll
16:31:02:406    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.ComponentModel.dll [External]
16:31:02:579    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll
16:31:02:579    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
16:31:02:579    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
16:31:02:957    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll [External]
16:31:02:966    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
16:31:02:966    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
16:31:02:977    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ObjectModel.dll
16:31:02:978    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.dll
16:31:03:001    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.ObjectModel.dll [External]
16:31:03:136    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.dll [External]
16:31:03:164    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.dll
16:31:03:166    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.dll
16:31:03:167    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
16:31:03:220    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.dll [External]
16:31:03:275    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.dll [External]
16:31:03:309    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll [External]
16:31:03:313    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
16:31:03:385    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll [External]
16:31:03:402    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.Uri.dll
16:31:03:432    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Private.Uri.dll [External]
16:31:03:458    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Loader.dll
16:31:03:470    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Loader.dll [External]
16:31:03:492    Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointCheckpoint()' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:418 [0x00000].
16:31:03:515    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Memory.dll
16:31:03:526    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Memory.dll [External]
16:31:03:532    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll
16:31:03:533    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll
16:31:03:533    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
16:31:03:544    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll [External]
16:31:03:557    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll [External]
16:31:03:570    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll [External]
16:31:03:574    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
16:31:03:588    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll [External]
16:31:03:639    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.dll
16:31:03:933    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.dll [External]
16:31:03:980    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
16:31:04:003    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll [External]
16:31:04:045    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.dll
16:31:04:048    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
16:31:04:048    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
16:31:04:048    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
16:31:04:082    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.dll [External]
16:31:04:099    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll [External]
16:31:04:116    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll [External]
16:31:04:165    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll [External]
16:31:04:165    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll
16:31:04:165    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll
16:31:04:165    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll
16:31:04:402    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll [External]
16:31:04:783    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll [External]
16:31:04:815    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll [External]
16:31:04:879    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll
16:31:04:879    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.dll
16:31:04:879    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll
16:31:04:879    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common.dll
16:31:04:879    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState.dll
16:31:04:966    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll [External]
16:31:04:990    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.dll [External]
16:31:05:022    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll [External]
16:31:05:054    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common.dll [External]
16:31:05:070    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState.dll [External]
16:31:05:070    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout.dll
16:31:05:070    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll
16:31:05:070    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime.dll
16:31:05:100    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout.dll [External]
16:31:05:132    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll [External]
16:31:05:168    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime.dll [External]
16:31:05:208    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Net.Primitives.dll
16:31:05:260    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Net.Primitives.dll [External]
16:31:05:260    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
16:31:05:274    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll [External]
16:31:05:280    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
16:31:05:292    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll [External]
16:31:05:387    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
16:31:05:388    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.Xml.dll
16:31:05:403    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll [External]
16:31:05:880    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Private.Xml.dll [External]
16:31:05:899    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
16:31:05:910    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll [External]
16:31:05:921    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
16:31:05:957    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll [External]
16:31:06:134    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
16:31:06:144    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll [External]
16:31:06:400    [companyname.ug] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 513(76KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 1952KB/2603KB, paused 719us total 5.393ms
16:31:06:897    Thread started:  #2
16:31:06:908    Thread started:  #3
16:31:06:920    Thread started:  #4
16:31:06:947    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll
16:31:06:949    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll
16:31:06:949    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll
16:31:06:967    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll [External]
16:31:07:134    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll [External]
16:31:07:154    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll [External]
16:31:07:172    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
16:31:07:188    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll [External]
16:31:07:523    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView.dll
16:31:07:532    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView.dll
16:31:07:668    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView.dll [External]
16:31:07:691    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView.dll [External]
16:31:07:745    [libEGL] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
16:31:07:754    [libEGL] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
16:31:07:759    [libEGL] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
16:31:07:769    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll
16:31:07:798    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll [External]
16:31:07:914    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.dll
16:31:08:043    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.dll [External]
16:31:08:144    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll
16:31:08:174    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll [External]
16:31:08:328    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll
16:31:08:350    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll [External]
16:31:08:415    [companyname.ug] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
16:31:08:415    [companyname.ug] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
16:31:08:651    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager2.dll
16:31:08:675    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager2.dll [External]
16:31:08:795    [CompatibilityChangeReporter] Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10107; state: ENABLED
16:31:08:802    [TabLayout] MODE_SCROLLABLE + GRAVITY_FILL is not supported, GRAVITY_START will be used instead
16:31:08:807    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll
16:31:08:827    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll [External]
16:31:09:022    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager.dll
16:31:09:051    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager.dll [External]
16:31:09:355    Thread started: .NET Timers #5
16:31:09:407    [HostConnection] createUnique: call
16:31:09:407    [HostConnection] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7bdc23255cd0, tid 5946
16:31:09:413    [HostConnection] HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
16:31:09:427    [OpenGLRenderer] Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
16:31:09:427    [OpenGLRenderer] Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
16:31:09:435    [EGL_emulation] eglCreateContext: 0x7bdc23253450: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
16:31:09:462    [EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0x7bdc23253450: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x7bde470f3080) (first time)
16:31:09:481    [Gralloc4] mapper 4.x is not supported
16:31:09:484    [HostConnection] createUnique: call
16:31:09:485    [HostConnection] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7bdc23254950, tid 5946
16:31:09:485    [goldfish-address-space] allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
16:31:09:485    [goldfish-address-space] allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f7ffe000 size 0x2000
16:31:09:487    [Gralloc4] allocator 4.x is not supported
16:31:09:496    [HostConnection] HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
16:31:10:979    [EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=110.69ms min=3.17ms max=809.25ms count=8
16:31:12:350    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
16:31:12:366    Thread started: .NET ThreadPool Gate #7
16:31:12:389    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
16:31:12:407    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll
16:31:12:432    Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ugg/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll [External]
16:31:12:874    [companyname.ug] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 2592(443KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3397KB/6794KB, paused 1.341ms total 11.527ms
```

After the app splash screen and the app main page is loaded:

```
16:31:13:715    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
16:31:13:715    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
16:31:13:922    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #11
16:31:33:834    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #8
16:31:33:850    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #9
16:31:33:898    The thread 0x8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
16:31:33:898    The thread 0x9 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
16:31:53:863    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #6
16:31:53:895    The thread 0x6 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
16:32:05:999    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #12
16:32:26:005    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #11
16:32:26:208    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #13
16:32:26:212    The thread 0xb has exited with code 0 (0x0).
16:32:46:455    The thread 0xa has exited with code 0 (0x0).
16:32:48:221    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #10
```

Comment: Something you don't want might be hanging around, either in build, or on device: * Delete all .bin and .obj folders. * delete `.vs` folder from solution. * Uninstall app from device, to make sure everything is gone. (Or for emulator, Reset to Factory, to have fresh device.) * Turn off Hot Reload, and try again. (Then if you want Hot Reload, turn it back on after you succeed.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks but that didn't help any. I edited my question and added an excerpt from the output window. It's failing to load assemblies, but then it loads them?

Comment: Those lines are normal. It looks one place, then looks another place where it is found. * What output lines appear immediately before/during/after the long delay? * Also, do you have older version of .csproj in source control, before you changed to .net 7? If so, see if anything changed during this experiment. * Another test: make a brand new Maui solution and project, see if it deploys quickly. Does it?

Comment: I tried an older version of the .csproj file, that didn't work. Fresh emulator didn't work.  Fresh project takes about the same amount of time.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I updated my question with output window results at the different stages of a new app. I'm really suspecting all the failed loads holding up my apps.

Comment: *"failed loads":* when there are several in a row, look at the times. They differ by a few milliseconds at most. Then when there finally is a load, its a bit longer (because it takes some milliseconds to actually load something.) This says to me that the test for an assembly in a given location is a negligible amount of time. It would take hundreds of failed loads to add up to a single second. (Not sure why they don't use less alarming wording. Think of it as: **"assembly looked for at location XYZ, checking next location."**)

Comment: Did you download from github **to a new folder**? [To be sure no VS settings are associated with the current copy of project.] Other than that, unless its something about the SSD|disk its loading from, or other OS caching, it might be time to delete all versions of VS and the emulator, start all over from nothing.

Comment: I downloaded to a new folder. Still the same ~20secs. I think I'm psyching myself out with this load time stuff. I have no definitive frame of reference for startup times before I noticed it taking longer. Fast deployment did wind up helping, but I don't know what the original startup time was. Bah, memory. Thanks for the help @ToolmakerSteve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast deployment is in YourProject / Properties / Android / Options:

**Fast deployment**
Use fast deployment (debug mode only).
[checked] Debug & net6.0-android

---

When the above is NOT checked, the following is added to .csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net6.0-android|AnyCPU'">
  <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This sped it up by about 30 seconds. Now it only hangs around for about 20 seconds. Better, but not how it was before.

Comment: Already checked, still slow, takes 2 minutes and more MAUI with .NET8

Comment: Build+Deploy for my app takes about 5 minutes.  It was down to around 1 minute with the latest Xamarin. Fucking ridiculous.